# Windows forms - catch pressed key in main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "notepad";
    info.UseShellExecute = true;
    var process = Process.Start(info);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
}

private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("asd");
}
```

Now, whenever I press a key while Form1 has focus, it detects it just fine. But when I start typing text in notepad - Form1 doesn't see the keys I press. How can I make that Form1 can catch the keys I press?

Comment: you do know that key loggers are considered malicious software and are likely to be blocked by an antivirus software, right?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a keylogger kind of software. It works even if the form is not focused. Check this link out. It should be able to help you.

http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/